# Fotorama and bootstrap modal not working at small screen sizes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, fotorama

I am using fotorama and bootstrap on a new site and for some reason when the site hits the sm breakpoint fotorama stops working, actually everything below the nav stops working. You can see this is action here

[bootstrap issue](http://capebeads.storeswarm.com/store/product/2)

So to replicate the issue have a look at the page in a desktop browser and everything should work the big add to cart button and the image slider. Then resize your browser or look at the site on mobile and try the buy button or the image slider and neither of them work.

Any help is really appreciated I have tried everything I can think of.

Comment: @IlyasDattoo I updated the link so it is working now. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

So I got the answer it turns out it was a z-index issue this line of css solved it.

```
.fotorama,.addToCart{position:relative;z-index:2;}
```